# How to organize sound library of a multi effect pedal?

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I'm planning to buy a BOSS ME-25 multi-effect processor. I'm wondering how to organize different kind of tones in the library.

For an example, let's take Decode by Paramore. This song has a clean tone and OD tone. The pedal I mentioned here has 60 memory locations. And Nothing else matters by Metallica has also 2 types of tones. So how should I organize these tones. Are there any tips to organize these tones according to tones? Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend trying tonal order with 4 sounds per group without focus on a songs. Too big groups will be hard to remember. To many presets will by hard to cycle and maintain. Especially in units that can cycle them only sequentially.

Focusing on songs may be great for gigs but would produce a lot of presets with little differences.

Example by distortion:

1. Clean
2. Clean+Comp+Reverb
3. Clean+Chorus and delay
4. ...
5. Light overdvrive
6. Overdive
7. Metalzone
8. ...
9. Solo tone1
10. Solo tone2
11. ...
12. Rarely used crazy tone 1
13. Rarely used crazy tone 2

Due to you want to be able to switch easily from clean to OD I would try to have specify less natural order covered by example 2

Example by Genre:

1. Country clean
2. Country lead
3. Country clean + comp
4. Metal Clean
5. Metal Rhythm
6. Metal Lead
7. Metal Chorus
8. Metal Rhythm (copy of 5 or new)
9. Metal lead
10. Punk clean
11. Punk lead
12. Punk rhythm
13. Punk flanged

Comment: What if I want to switch instantly from 1 to 6?

Comment: I would personally use volume on guitar but then you can place them closer and organize them by genre not the amount of distortion. Units that can only go up and down with presets are not good for that kind of playing and you need compromise

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where and when you want to use the pedal, ultimately. If you are planning a setlist then I would order your presets to follow the set. I would also order your presets by overall gain level. When I used to play guitar in a band I was using a Korg AX10G. I used three patches primarily. The first was clean, the second was an overdrive/boost, and the third was the highest gain setting which I only used once or twice during a set. I did this for simplicity's sake, as I didn't want to be jumping through weird and surprising patches to get to my next patch, especially on stage.

For the two songs you highlighted I would configure patches A1 and A2 for the clean and dirty tones of Song 1, and patches A3 and A4 for the clean and dirty tones of song 2, etc. Boss' nomenclature may vary, but I would stack patches this way.

Comment: Your suggestion at the end is very helpful. I think its a better way to organize tones (according to songs). So I have to memorize which patch locations goes with which songs.